# Error "python: not found" in Dockerized PHP application hosted on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a PHP application which will compile Python code upon submission from users and then return the result. The application is hosted on Elastic Beanstalk and it is working fine until I wish to have it runs within a Docker container.

For the working version, I deploy the application on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk running on a platform `64bit Amazon Linux with PHP 7.0` and submit a simple code, for example, `print(1+1)`, I will get the result as `2`.

To run the application within a Docker container, I followed the instructions from the tutorial
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html#create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial_connect
, modified its `php-app` folder to contain my own PHP application and set the platform to `Multi-container Docker`.

However, when I tried to submit a simple code like `print(1+1)`, I got the result as
`Array
(
    [0] => sh: 1: python: not found
)`

I checked with my EC2 instance and confirmed that the instance has python installed. The PHP application should not have caused this error(I guess) since it is running perfectly on another platform. So my problem is why can't I get the result instead of having a `python not found` error?

I am new to AWS and Docker. Please forgive me if I am not expressing my problem clear enough. Do let me know if you need my console output in EC2 instance or my application files or whatever that helps. All bits of help are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When running the PHP application in the container, you're using the php:fpm base image, which doesn't come with Python installed. Ideally, you'd write your own Dockerfile and list Python as one of your dependencies. If you want to stick to the Elastic Beanstalk format, one way to get around this is by ensuring that Python is installed when starting the container. The cotainerDefinitions parameter in Dockerrun.aws.json allows, according to the documentation, to include the usual parameters of an ECS Task Definition, so you can include one more field called "command" (which maps to the CMD command in the Docker API), and set it to ["apt-get", "update", "&&", "apt-get", "install", "python"]:

```
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "php-app",
      "image": "php:fpm",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "php-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
          "readOnly": true,
          "command": ["apt-get", "update", "&&", "apt-get", "install", "python"]
        }
      ]
    },
```

That will install Python when spinning up the container, and make it available to the PHP application. 
Alternatively, you can create your own base image from php:fpm, install Python on it, upload it to ECR, and include its URI in the containerDefinitions: image parmeter (instead of php:fpm).

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping, but I still received the same error after adding the field. Did I happen to miss out certain steps in deploying my application? First, I zip `php-app, proxy and Dockerrun.aws` and upload this zipped file to EB. Then I send a simple code to the PHP server and I expect to receive the result. This is how I did it every time.  
I also tried to SSH into my EC2 instance and executed the `sudo docker run php:fpm` command, yet I still had the same error.